# JSF Base64 error?

Tags: maven, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, base64

I'm building a page with JSF (using Maven, Eclipse and Tomcat 7). Developing with JSF is new to me but for a university project we have to use JSF. I read a lot of tutorials about getting started with JSF and I could solve a lot of problems on my own.

Now I get a error that is generated by MyFaces. It says:

```
An Error Occurred:
org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

viewId=/eingabe.xhtml
location=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/NewProject/index.xhtml
phaseId=RENDER_RESPONSE(6)

Caused by:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
```

index.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"      
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h:form>
        <h:outputLabel value="Name:"  for="name"></h:outputLabel>
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{customer.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:commandButton id="save" action="#{customer.save}" value="Save"></h:commandButton>
    </h:form>

</body>
</html>
```

The error is generated by MyFaces and not by Apache. I have no idea what I have to look for and where the error comes from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your application depends on [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

You need to get the jar file and add it to WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Thank's, that worked. I just had to add the dependency ([link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4)) to my pom.xml :)